# C# Simple app to spam button from keyboard

Tags: c#, keyboard, spam

I want to make simple C# form application. It will contain 1 textbox and 1 button. In textbox i write what button from keyboard i want to be spammed this button. But i dont know how to write this code to spam this button. I know how to get button from textbox, but now how to spam this button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    Button btn = new Button();
    public Form1()
    {
        btn.Top = tb.Bottom;
        btn.Text = "Click here to press key";
        Controls.Add(tb);
        Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += Btn_Click;
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait(tb.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid key to send");
        }
    }
}
```